# Windows Icon property in WPF, Markup Extension needed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an icon that I added to my application.  It shows up in the first window that gets presented.  When I present a new window, and I use the

```
Icon="ApplicationIcon.ico"
```

in my Window, it crashes.  When I remove that line, my code runs fine.  I'm trying to get rid of the default icon Windows provides and use the one that my application is using.  I double checked the path, but it does not work.  I get the error:

> Xaml parse exception occurred: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '7' and line position '9'.

```
Inner Exception: {"Cannot locate resource 'views/applicationicon.ico'."}
System.IO.IOException: {"Cannot locate resource 'views/applicationicon.ico'."}
```

Comment: Look at the inner exception in the debugger and post that as well..

Comment: Are you using Windows XP?  If so, is the Icon you're trying to use formatted for Windows Vista/7 (ie. has resolutions higher than 48px)

Comment: H.B., how do I look at the inner exception in the debugger?  I'm using VS2010.  I am new to VS in general...

Comment: @Crystal: In that exception popup box click "View Details" at the bottom, in the window that opens expand the first node and look for the entry called "InnerException", the value next to that is the inner exception message. There may be even more inner exceptions, so expand nodes as long as there are any and post all their messages. (btw, i did not get your message, you need to use `@H.B.`)

Comment: @H.B., I did not know the @ sign worked that way.  How neat!  I added the inner exceptions.

Comment: @H.B., you the man. I can see in that exception that the path is incorrect! Thanks dude!  Can I mark your comment as answered somehow?  I clicked that little arrow up.  Maybe there are other features on the site I do not know about!

Comment: @Crystal: Yeah, it looks like it's relative to the location of your other windows. Comments cannot be accepted, but i could post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is relative and for windows located in other places it will not work, you could make it absolute using [pack notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
Icon="pack://application:,,,/ApplicationIcon.ico"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using the the application icon incorrectly. Since this is a WPF application you should have a WPF project in your workspace. Select that project's properties and go to "Application". Under resources you can select the relative location of your icon which will then replace the default WPF app icon. Note that the icon doesn't usually appear when the application is run in debug mode. To make it appear the app should be run without debugging or in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Use single file for all you WPF windows in your solution By setting following........**

Icon="pack://application:,,,/ReferenceAssemblyname;component/Subfoldername/filename.ico"

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a wild guess here and say that your other windows are not in the same folder than your main window. If that's the case, add `".."`, something like `"..\ApplicationIcon.ico"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  I ended up setting the Build Action for the icon to 'Content' and set the Copy to Output Directory option to 'Copy always', and it worked like a charm.